# Head title not being server side rendered in Inertiajs ssr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I have managed to get ssr to work with Inertiajs inside Laravel project. In this simple about page it gets rendered on the server but not the Head title. Why is the title not being rendered on the server side ?

```
import { Link, Head } from '@inertiajs/react';
import { PageProps } from '@/types';

export default function About({...props}) {
    return (
        <>
            <Head title="About" />
            <h1 className="text-red-200">{props.title}</h1>
            <p>{props.body}</p>
            <Link href="/">Home</Link>
            
        </>
    );
}
```

Check offical documentation but couldn't find any thing related to the issue